# creating many similar elements in javascript animation

Tags: javascript, jquery, animation

For a javascript animation, I am trying to create buttons with the numbers 1-9 on them. Right now my javascript for the number 1 looks like:

```
that1 = { thisx : 120, thisy: H-400, thisnumber= "1",

draw: function() {
    var keywidth = 100; 
    var keyheight = 150 ; 
    var x = this.thisx;
    var y = this.thisy;
    var cornercut = 5;
ctx.beginPath();

//drawing the key
ctx.moveTo(x, y+cornercut);
ctx.quadraticCurveTo(x,y, x+cornercut, y);
ctx.lineTo(x+keywidth-cornercut, y);
ctx.quadraticCurveTo(x+keywidth, y, x+keywidth, y+cornercut);
ctx.lineTo(x+keywidth, y+keyheight-cornercut);
ctx.quadraticCurveTo(x+keywidth, y+keyheight, x+keywidth-cornercut, y+keyheight);
ctx.lineTo(x+cornercut, y+keyheight);
ctx.quadraticCurveTo(x, y+keyheight, x, y+keyheight-cornercut);
ctx.lineTo(x, y+cornercut);

ctx.closePath();

ctx.stroke();

ctx.fillText(this.thisnumber, x+.5*keywidth,y+.8*keyheight); 

},

highlight: function() {

ctx.fillStyle="red";
ctx.fill();

} 

} ;
```

I could just copy this to create this2, this3, this4, this5, etc., but I feel like there is an easier way. Can anyone help? I am using JS because I believe it will be the easiest way to control these objects using animation, but please let me know if you have another suggestion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could change the values of `thisx` and `thisy` and simply call the `draw` function again, but the code would probably be more elegant if you simply passed in the values as arguments to a draw function.

Comment: I have another draw() function elsewhere that draws the whole canvas. Maybe not the best naming. So for now I am calling this as that1.draw() Is there an easy way to make similar that2.draw() etc  or must I copy paste?